# Dynamic variables in Hash JS

Tags: javascript, dynamic, hash

How can I have a dynamic variaible in a hash like follows:

```js
key = dynamicVariaible

plugin.varibles = {
        [key + "1"]            : "1",
        [key + "Ctrl-2" ]      : "2",
}
```

Using the above I have been getting the error: `ExecJS::ProgramError: Unexpected token: name (key)`

Comment: Working here.. https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/yrsna3ox/

Answer (score 0):

You can create dynamic variable, try this :

```
key = "1"

var plugin = {
        [key + "1"]            : "1",
        [key + "Ctrl-2" ]      : "2",
}
```

there might be issue in `dynamicVariaible`

Comment: Is there an alternative way of doing this? I am getting an error when compiling assets and I have pinned it to the use of `[key + '1']`

Comment: could you please post some relevant source code, so that we can investigate actual issue. Also would like to mention that there is not any error in this line of code.

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
var key  = "2"; 
var variables = {};
variables[ key + "1" ]=1;
variables[ key + "Ctrl-2" ]=2;
```

I am not sure if you can give dynamic property names while initializing the object.

Answer (score 0):

In ES6, you could use [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer):

```js
var key = 'dummy',
    plugin = {};

plugin.variables = {
    [key + '1']: "1",
    [key + 'Ctrl-2']: "2",
};

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(plugin, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

In ES5, this would work as the same:

```js
var key = 'dummy',
    plugin = { variables: {} };

plugin.variables[key + '1'] = "1";
plugin.variables[key + 'Ctrl-2'] = "2",

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(plugin, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```